# Syntax error in creating store procedure, what is wrong with my code

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

what is wrong with my code? I came from sql server never thought mysql is too sensitive

this is my script below

[image]

it always points that there is an error on block
**SET @totalPages = page_number * page_size;**

Answer (score 0):

got it working, problem is I placed the declaration outside **BEGIN** statement, it should be inside